# variable is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

As mentioned in the title, my variable "isModUp" is "declared but its value is never read"

```
client.on("message", (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    if(self) return;
    const badges = tags.badges || {};
    const isBroadcaster = badges.broadcaster;
    const isMod = badges.moderator;
    const isModUp = isMod || isBroadcaster
});
```

I have copied some code off GitHub and for some reason this issue has never happened to anyone else. I use this variable here:

```
if(message.isModUp ("!gta.on")){
    client.say(channelName, "!title [EN/PC] GTA V W/VIEWERS! | !sc to join | !discord | !youtube | !socials| !nerdordie| #RazerStreamer")
    client.say(channelName, "!game Grand Theft Auto V")
}

if(message.isModUp ("!warface.on")){
    client.say(channelName, "!title [EN/PC] Playing Warface by myself! | !discord | !youtube | !socials| !nerdordie| #RazerStreamer #AMA #Solo")
    client.say(channelName, "!game Warface")
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You are not using the `isModUp` variable, exactly as the error says. Doing `message.isModUp` accesses the `isModUp` property of the `message` object - it doesn't reference the standalone variable `isModUp`.

Comment: how would i go about making isModUp useful. i am using this to make a twitch bot and i want to add mod only commands

Comment: i tried removing the line of code `isModUp = isMod || isBroadcaster` but now `isMod` and `isBroadcaster` both get "declared but vlaue is never read"

Comment: ***What*** is reporting *"declared but its value is never read"*? [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)? Some build system? Something else? On what platform (hardware, operating system, software (all, including versions and editions))? When does it happen?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that nowhere else does the variable isModUp appear and that the message variable is not a set that has a function called isModUp because isModUp is not a function anyway. In that case, there is the variable isModUp is defined but the value is never used so it would be save space and computer processing power to just remove that line of code.

Comment: i need to use the ismodup variable else idk how to make my message mod only and above

Comment: Well the problem is that the variable is declared in a function which means that it is not global and can't be used outside of a function, so if this is node.js, you would have to declare it outside using let or var instead of const, and then give it its value inside the function so that it is still global.